# Remove cut/copy/paste from context menu in Win10

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu

I would like to remove some options from context menu in WinExplorer.

Usually try to avoid using mouse. Context menu activate by Shift+F10 then choose needed options by arrows. All time I need to go throught "cut/copy/paste/customize folder/group by/order by" etc. I don't need this options in context menu.

How can I achieve it? I use windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this app to your goal
[image: Windows Tweaker]

[For Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/downloads/UWT4.zip)

[For Windows 8 - 8.1](http://anonymz.com/?http://www.thewindowsclub.com/downloads/UWT3.zip?8c730d)

[For Windows 7](http://anonymz.com/?http://www.thewindowsclub.com/downloads/UWT.zip?8c730d)

Comment: There is no option for remove Cut/Copy/Paste fields from context menu or I can not fint them.